# I'm making a second API Call to Youtube API but it's not giving me the full results

Tags: python, pandas, youtube-api

My goal is to be able to get all the statistics in the second API Call for all the videos i've pulled via my first API call.

-My first API Call was this line of code, which worked.

```py
#Make API call

pageToken = ""

url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key="+API_KEY+"&part=snippet&channelType=any&q=datascience|datascientist&chart=mostPopular&order=viewCount&maxResults=10000"+pageToken

response = requests.get(url).json()
```

-Then i wrote a for loop in order to be able to take the specific attributes that i needed from the call, hence why i used "video_id" in the second call, Hoping it will work.

-Here is the problem, my second call. Here is my code

```py
#2nd API CALL

video_stats_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id="+video_id+"&part=statistics&key="+API_KEY
response_2 = requests.get(video_stats_url).json()
```

- Here is the result that i got :

```json
{'kind': 'youtube#videoListResponse',
 'etag': 'SEChKKwRYynfnHVdplNK7DBgSJg',
 'items': [{'kind': 'youtube#video',
   'etag': '5_tBknUTvLB7i91b074xOhccd3U',
   'id': 'pzo13OPXZS4',
   'statistics': {'viewCount': '121146',
    'likeCount': '1939',
    'favoriteCount': '0',
    'commentCount': '49'}}],
 'pageInfo': {'totalResults': 1, 'resultsPerPage': 1}}
```

Please help. The goal is to be able to get the statistics of all the videos i pulled in the first API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified in the [google api video endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) docs, you can simply add multiple id parameters to your request in order to retrieve the statistics for multiple videos.

For eg:

```py
searchUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key="+API_KEY+"&part=snippet&channelType=any&q=datascience|datascientist&chart=mostPopular&order=viewCount&maxResults=10000"+pageToken

response = requests.get(searchUrl).json()

statsUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&key="+API_KEY

for vid in response['items']:
    video_stats_url += "&id=" + vid['id']['videoId']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I Was hoping that i could loop through the video ID'S instead of manually typing all of it in. I'm new to coding sorry if i'm being annoying. The code works, just looking for more efficiency

Comment: @Quadri You can use the search response to grab the video ids. I updated the answer to show how to do that. We all started somewhere :)

Comment: @Quadri No problem, if this resolves your issue it would be nice if you accept it as answer (by clicking on the checkmark left to the answer).